# TCL custom sorting

Tags: sorting, tcl

I would appreciate any help on this as I am new to TCL. I created a list of strings by doing a 'regexp -all -line -inline' + criterion on the output of a CLI command. Each element of this list now ends with a number and I want to sort the list on this particular numeric ending in each string but preserve the rest of the string. A close example would be to have to sort the output of the '`ls -la`' command by the size of the files. I tried the following but it did not work:

```
lsort -command  "regexp -lineanchor {\d+$}" -integer $list
```

After spending a day on trying to figure this out I decided to ask you guys. Would you be able to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, I don't understand what you want to achieve with `-command "regexp -lineanchor {\d+$}"`. The command `regexp -lineanchor {\d+$}` should actually always return 1 if you plan to compare numbers.

If you want to sort a list by the last element of its sublists you can use the `-index` option. E.g.:

```
lsort -index end -integer {{x y 5} {a b 8} {c c 3} {u u 1} {x y 2}}
```

returns:

```
{u u 1} {x y 2} {c c 3} {x y 5} {a b 8}
```

If you don't have your data in sublists but have the data line by line you have to `split` it before, e.g.:

```
lsort -index end -integer [split $data "\n"]
```

Comment: bmk, you are the BEST!!! This is exactly what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you very much!

Comment: @torta: I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: +1 but I'd do a separate step to extract the words from each line before sorting on the grounds that there's no guarantee that the other command will understand words in quite the same way as Tcl.